# change of variable to get a quasi-cartesian laplace equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, change-of-variable, cylindrical-coordinates

when writing the (vector) laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates in a $(r,\theta)$ plane, we get:
$$ \left( r^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} \right)A_z(r,\theta)=0 $$
the term $r^2$ is multiplied by the two sides of the equation to form the cauchy-Euler equation.

now through a change of variable of $v=\ln(r)$:
$$ \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial v^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} \right)A_z(v,\theta)=0 $$
it is like a cartesian laplace operator, which has its advantages of simplification of computations.

however in $(r,z)$ plane the laplace equation becomes as following:
$$ \left( r^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} -1 + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \right)A_\theta(r,z)=0 $$
is it even possible through a change of $u=f(r)$ to get a result like the same?:
$$ \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \right)A_\theta(u,z)=0 $$

additional notes:it is worth noting that in the above equations, the 3D vector-laplace equation has been reduced to 2D plane due to symmetry of the problem.

Comment: There's something off about those Laplacians, the units are not correct

Comment: yes I noticed, I corrected the notation. I think the problem is clear now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible. a Cauchy-Euler equation in terms of radial component appears in the partial equation which cannot be transformed into a simple second-order derivative.

Dear readers, for proof, please refer to this question:

[Reduce the Cauchy-Euler equation to a smaller expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964129/reduce-the-cauchy-euler-equation-to-a-smaller-expression)

Answer (score 0):

$$r^2\nabla^2 = \left( r^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} \right)$$
The Laplacien should be:
$$\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac 1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \dfrac 1 {r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} $$
And:
$$\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac 1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \dfrac 1 {r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} +\dfrac {\partial^2}{\partial z^2} $$

Comment: yes, I should have known. I corrected the notation, thanks.

Comment: No problem you are welcome @HoseinJavanmardi

Comment: thank you Mr. Aryadeva, any ideas for the clarified problem?