# Reduce the Cauchy-Euler equation to a smaller expression?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conformal-geometry, change-of-variable

Given the Cauchy-Euler second order differential equation:
$$ \left( x^2\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + x\frac{d}{d x} -1\right)y(x)=0 $$
is it possible to find a function $u(x)$ , which satisfies the following simple form:?
$$ \frac{d^2 y(u)}{d u^2}=0 $$
***notice that $t=\ln(x)$ yields:
$$ \frac{d^2 y(t)}{d t^2}-1=0 $$

Comment: You're looking for the solution to $\frac{d^2 y(u)}{du^2} = 0$?  This is perhaps the second-best known differential equation of all time.

Comment: $\frac{d^2 y(u)}{d u^2}=0$ or $\frac{d^2 y(u)}{d x^2}=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that t=ln(x) yields:
$$\dfrac {d^2y(t)}{dt^2}−1=0$$

---

$$
\left( x^2\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + x\frac{d}{d x} -1\right)y(x)=0$$
It yields:
$$\dfrac {d^2y(t)}{dt^2}−\color {red}{y(t)}=0$$
That you can rewrite as:
$$y''+y'-y'-y=0$$
$$(ze^{-t})'=0$$
Where $z=y'+y$.
$$((ye^t)'e^{-2t})'=0$$

---

Note that:
$$\frac{d^2 y(u)}{d u^2}=0$$
Has solution:
$$y(u)=c_1u+c_2$$
But $c_2$ is not a solution of the original equation:
$$ x^2\frac{d^2y}{d x^2} + x\frac{dy}{d x} -y=0$$
So it 's not possible to find such $u=u(x)$.

Comment: But c2 is not a solution of the original equation: that's the mark.

Comment: I also provided an answer. but your answer seems to be sufficient and brief. thanks.

Comment: Nica answer @HoseinJavanmardi You "re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
x^{2}y'' + xy' - y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y'' + 2xy') - (xy' + y) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y')' - (xy)' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y' - xy = c_{0}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you, it is a smart hint but I don't understand the relation with the question

Answer (score 0):

we suppose that there exits a $u(x)$, if so; using chain rule we have:
$$ \frac{d^2y}{du^2} = \left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{dx}{du} \frac{d\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)}{dx} \frac {dy}{dx}$$
now setting this equal to the main equation:
$$ x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} -y $$
there is an extra term in the main equation ($-y$) which cannot be found.
however if this extra term didnot exist, we'd have:
$$ \left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} $$
$$ \frac{dx}{du} \frac{d\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)}{dx} \frac {dy}{dx} = x\frac{dy}{dx} $$
these two equations are dependant, i.e. a solution to one of them is a solution to the other. therefore solving the first one suggests:
$$ u = \ln(x) $$
this is valid for the second one, too.

Answer (score 0):

Starting backwards from the solution $y=c_1x+c_2x^{-1}$, if you set $xy(x)=f(x^2)$, then you get for the derivatives
$$
xy'+y=2xf'(x^2)\\
xy''+2y'=4x^2f''(x^2)+2f'(x^2)
$$
so that
$$
0=x^2y''+xy'-y=4x^3f''(x^2).
$$
This gives the expected equation $f''=0$, but not exactly the way you were looking for.